# How to scroll to the selected form field when key board shown in android app with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I used this code to window scroll top in android app. but its scrolling total body. not till to selected form field. I want scroll till to selected form field.

`here is my code`

```
var is_keyboard = false;
        var is_landscape = false;
        var initial_screen_size = window.innerHeight;

        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            var currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
            is_keyboard = (window.innerHeight < initial_screen_size);
            is_landscape = (screen.height < screen.width);
            var keyboardSize = (initial_screen_size - currentHeight);

            if (keyboardSize > 0) {
                alert("Keyboard is shown! Size is: " + keyboardSize);
            } else {
                alert("Keyboard is closed!");
            }

            alert('Screen resized. currentHeight: ' + currentHeight + " - OriginalHeight: " + initial_screen_size);

        }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to selected field you need to set a class or id on that element on capturing the event you need to check the flag on that element and then
 find the offset and scroll the document to it.
Hope this helps

```
if (scroll_flag == ' scroll1'){ 
      var fooOffset = $('#gift').offset(),
        destination = fooOffset.top;
        console.log(destination);
      $(document).scrollTop(destination);
    }
```